# getting eclipse duplicate line shortcut to work on fedora 19 ctrl+alt+Up/Down

Tags: eclipse, fedora

getting eclipse duplicate line shortcut to work on fedora 19 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> And  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

by default these key combination are mapped to the switch workplace up/down function and while in older fedora versions it was possible to disable them through `Settings --> keyboard --> shortcut ...` but this doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 8):

open a console window (terminal) with the same user you use to run eclipse
execute the following commands to free up the key binding

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['']"
```

source: [fedora bug report and workaround](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=982695)

Comment: This works with Ubuntu 16.04+ too. Changing the shortcut in the OS preferences didn't change anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, go to the Keys preference page in Eclipse and change the bindings there.